# discord.js unban command error when not given an id to unban

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bots, discord.js

I've been following [this discord.js bot tutorial serie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w24f9qa_qmw&list=PLWnw41ah3I4ZfNLV3by7nB6JO2WcCc3Wj&index=12) and I found an error I'm not capable of solving. The command works when you give it an id but when you don't give it anything it doesn't show the error line it should show giving me an error in the console.

This is the code without some of the unnecesary lines or the ones that works:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const botconfig = require("../botconfig.json");
const colours = require("../colours.json");


module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => { 

    if(!message.member.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send("...")

    let bannedMember = await bot.users.fetch(args[0])       //I believe the error is somewhere in this line maybe because of the promise
    if(!bannedMember) return message.channel.send("I need an ID")

    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
    if(!reason) reason = "..."


    try {
        message.guild.members.unban(bannedMember, {reason: reason})
        message.channel.send(`${bannedMember.tag} ha sido readmitido.`)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }


}
```

And this is the error:

```
(node:19648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: 404: Not Found
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\Bob\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:19648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was 
not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19648) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Also, when you give it something that is not an id like *!unban asdf* I have this error:

```
(node:17824) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
user_id: Value "asdf" is not snowflake.
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\Bob\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17824) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I don't know what is wrong with the first error and for the second error I guess I just have to check if `args[0]` is an *id* or *snowflake*, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to come with a proper solution for what I wanted to do but first I want to comment a couple things:
As Zer0 said, if `bannedMember = await bot.users.fetch(args[0])` returns an error and we check it with `if(!bannedMember)` it will be like `!!bannedMember` turning it into a true statement but, we have this definition for the *if* conditional statement:

[Use *if* to specify a block of code to be executed, if a specified condition is **true**.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

This is why we use `if(!condition)`to check if the *condition* was false.

But the problem here wasn't that. The problem was that the *await* function is blocs the async function. This means that if the *promise* it is waiting for doesn't arrive when called and it'll come with the error that I had without continuing with the rest of the code. Here is where comes the solution a friend gave me and the one I ended up using and it works perfectly:

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => { 

    if(!message.member.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send("You can't do that.")

    if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Give me a valid ID"); 
    //This if() checks if we typed anything after "!unban"

    let bannedMember;
    //This try...catch solves the problem with the await
    try{                                                            
        bannedMember = await bot.users.fetch(args[0])
    }catch(e){
        if(!bannedMember) return message.channel.send("That's not a valid ID")
    }

    //Check if the user is not banned
    try {
            await message.guild.fetchBan(args[0])
        } catch(e){
            message.channel.send('This user is not banned.');
            return;
        }

    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
    if(!reason) reason = "..."

    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send("I can't do that")
    message.delete()
    try {
        message.guild.members.unban(bannedMember, {reason: reason})
        message.channel.send(`${bannedMember.tag} was readmitted.`)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
}
```

I'm using Zer0's suggestion `if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Give me a valid ID");` to check if something was typed after the command *!unban* solving the first error.
To solve the second error and check if we got a valid ID we have the first *try...catch* were we can only pass through the *try* if we get a valid ID because of this:

- [*.users*](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users): All of the User objects that have been cached at any point, mapped by their IDs.
- [*.fetch()*](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=fetch): Fetches this user. Returns: Promise < User >.

If the *try* fails the *catch* runs an *if* to check if `bannedMember` is *false* and returns a message error.

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, I would just check if args[0] is given or not. I assume `bot.users.fetch` returns an error object so a `!!bannedMember` would evaluate as a true. Are you using Discord.js v12? This differs in v11 and v12, so I can't give you a clear answer for this right now. If you want to check what it returns, you can just console.log the banned member tho.

So my suggestion is:

```js
if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("please provide a valid ID");
```

Also it would be a total valid approach to just let the code below work like in order to catch your second error type

```js
    try {
        message.guild.members.unban(bannedMember, { reason });
        message.channel.send(`${bannedMember.tag} ha sido readmitido.`);
    } catch(e if e instanceof DiscordAPIError) {
        message.channel.send("Are you sure this is a valid user ID?");
    }
```

Comment: I'm using v12 and I tried the `if(!args[0])` but it didn't convinced me. I've ended up doing a try catch like this:
`let bannedMember;    try{bannedMember = await bot.users.fetch(args[0])}catch(e){if(!bannedMember) return message.channel.send("...")}`
Now it works fine. And I'm trying your solution but I'm getting an error expeting "()" somewhere in `catch(e if e instanceof DiscordAPIError)`. And I didn't think of `!!bannedMember` so I will check that as well.

Thanks a lot for your answer